# Publish Cocoapod from a GitHub hosted in a monorepo

Tags: swift, cocoapods, monorepo

Is there a suggested way to format the source attribute in a podspec file for a pod thats hosted in a monorepo? I have generated a cocoapod using the `pod lib create` utility. My pod however is hosted in a GitHub monorepo with this structure:

```
/proj1
/proj2
/shared/ios/MyCocoaPod
```

How should I specify the source in the podspec for this situation if the git repo has more that one project in it?

My current source is:

```
  s.source = { :git => 'https://github.com/myrepo.git' , :tag => "My-iOS-Pod-#{s.version}" }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `s.source` attribute should match. The different pods in the monorepo are distinguished by the files selected.

See examples in the podspecs at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk.

Comment: great example! Moved my podspec to the root and corrected the source paths. Thsnks.